# Hiding properties and methods of usercontrol class in C#

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a UserControl . Problem is when i dropped it into another form. It exposes all the properties and methods of user control which is a issue in my case.

I want to expose only that properties and methods which is in my CustomControl class not in UserControl class.

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works.

When I do the same in Visual Studio, the properies of `CustomControl` in the suggestions drop down is bold and properties of `UserControl` is normal text so it is easy to differentiate.